# How can I repair a textured ceiling without making a mess?

Tags: drywall, painting, ceiling

I have knocked out a couple walls and never really made it fit right with the ceiling pattern - [Is there an easy way to replicate this ceiling texture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32124/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replicate-this-ceiling-texture)

[image]

Also as time goes on I am noticing that the nails they used to hang the drywall are losing their bite.  This is only in the main living area which is completely open now.  So I need to probably hit most of the ceiling in this area with a lot of drywall screws.

I also have a couple of hairline cracks to fix too but these are rather small and have done that before.  So just lots of ceiling issues.

If I can get all of the furniture out of these 4 rooms (kitchen, front room, living room, dining room) - and these rooms are all open to each other - what kind of ceiling treatment can I use so that I do not have drywall dust all over my house and something that will deal with the already swirl/sand that I have?  (Acoustical texture isn't an option.)

Comment: Drop ceiling, but I'm guessing you don't want your home to look like office space. Maybe a [metal ceiling](http://www.armstrong.com/residential-ceilings/products/ceilings/metallaire-collection/_/N-1z141rfZ1z141sj)?

Comment: @Tester101 - Just looking for a nice thick coat of something so I don't have to sand down all of the swirls and rather not skim coat the entire ceiling 1000 sq/ft.   If this doesn't exist - it should.

Comment: I would hang .25 drywall on top of the existing ceiling

Comment: @MikeFlanagan - I might go this way but I am not sure this isn't an equal amount of mess.  Plus doing this I have to deal with all of the ceiling fixtures - and I have a lot.

Comment: I doubt that 1/4 inch drywall has the stiffness for use on a ceiling. Plus, the work to tape all those new seams wouldn't be less than scraping and re-texturing this.

Answer (score 1):

Caulk the hairline cracks. Pick out the nail pop plaster, screw the nail or screw back in with an adjacent screw to hold it in, spackle & prime. Then, re-paint the ceilings with a Sandy Paint or Add Sand to any paint.

Roll-on the new paint for everything. But then, go back with a brush to do a 2nd or 3rd coat with a brush. The brush will let you swirl & build-up any flat areas for a pretty perfect match quite easily.

[image: sandy paint]

Answer (score 0):

you can just spray it with a latex base sand texture coating (like stucco but finer)

http://durabond.com/products/plaster-acc/sandex/

you will have someone in your area that makes something similar.

Comment: One of the issues I have is rather not use a spray gun because we are talking about a finished house.  Also can you describe the install method?   This might be a good idea but would like to know more about how it goes up, thickness, sanding?, and anything else.

Comment: spray guns are used all the time in finished spaces.  just fill your cracks, etc. and then skim a thin layer of mud on to the ceiling.  roll it on with a stipple roller or high knap roller (you can thin the mud with water to make it flow better).  this will smooth out any irregularities in the existing ceiling texture to minimize obvious changes in texture.    then you tape plastic on the walls and floors (take furniture out first) and spray the sandex on with a pneumatic (not electric) texture sprayer.  take plastic off so that all the goop is inside the plastic as you roll it up.  done.

Comment: make sure you let all steps dry thoroughly between coats

Answer (score 0):

Get a bucket of drywall compound, some "PVA" primer, a 1/2" lambswool roller, a small container of plaster and a "Magic Squeegee" ( a very wide very flexible rubber blade).  Thin a gallon or so of drywall compound at a time in a bucket with the primer till it's a thick but liquid (rollable consistancy).  Add a cup full of plaster.  Take the roller, soak it in water... ring it out thoroughly and roll on your concoction onto the ceiling.  You will then gently use the squeegee to flatten it out and eliminate roller marks.  Take your time and go slow... you'll have at least an hour before it starts to set up